# React Native: Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a very simple react native screen which looks as follows:

```
class BasicScreen extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: [],
    myItems: [],
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.checkforItems();
  }
  checkforItems = async () => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('MyItems').then(item => {
      if (item) {
        this.setState({
          myItems: JSON.parse(item),
        });
      } else {
        console.log('No data.');
      }
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View>/* A detailed view */</View>
    )
  }
}
```

The problem is that it causes the following error:

```
Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component.
```

I'm not sure how to fix this. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like it is just going to overwrite `myItems` with whatever the most recent mapped `item` is rather than appending each new item.

You might try mapping the items to an array in `componentDidMount()` and then set the state in a `useEffect` call.

```
const BasicScreen = () => {
  const [myData, setData] = useState([]);
  const [myItems, setItems] = useState([]);

  const checkForItems = () => {
    var storageItems = AsyncStorage.getItem("MyItems").then((item) => {
      if (item) {
        return JSON.parse(item);
      }
    });
    setItems(storageItems);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getItems() {
      await checkForItems();
    }
    getItems();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{myItems[0]}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default BasicScreen;
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please elaborate on how I will do this? useEffect will be a separate function outside componentDidMount?

Comment: I read about it but I can't figure out how I can make a call to useEffect() from componentDidMount().

Comment: You would need to convert it to a function component. I updated the example code. Something similar to that, might need some tweaking based on the items from storage.

Comment: Ok thanks. This should work for me. I also have a few other functions in my code that need to be called by the user by clicking a button. Those functions will be outside the useEffect, right?

Comment: Yeah. Since the second value in useEffect is an empty array it will just run when the component mounts. It should function like `componentDidMount()` so you'd want other functions outside of that.

Comment: Thank you. There is just one more question. I had componentWIllMount() from where I was also calling a redux action and then I was receiving data as props in componentWillReceiveProps. With the new function component, both these are not available. So, from where should I trigger my redux action?

Comment: For the Redux action take a look here: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/using-redux-with-react-hooks#how-to-use-redux-with-hooks and here: https://medium.com/soluto-engineering/react-class-features-vs-hooks-equivalents-745368dafdb3#3012 for `componentWillReceiveProps()` equivalent.

Comment: Thanks. May be I can dispatch my action from useEffect()? But how will I update the state once the props our updated?

Comment: I'm not so sure but one problem I noticed is that storageItems is still a promise. So, the setItems(storageItems) is just getting set to a promise and not real values. It's looking like this - Storage items:  Promise {_U: 0, _V: 0, _W: null, _X: null} Can you help with how I can resolve that?